# R2 as a measure to compare simulation model outputs with real world data

Tags: regression, time-series, model-selection, simulation

I want to compare a price time series generated by a simulation model to real world price data. In the literature, I found a contribution (an A journal article in economics) in which R2 is used for a similar comparison.

However, I am confused whether it is possible to use R2 (among other indicators) to compare fundamental model outputs to data. Since the model is not a regression, the sum of residuals between the model and the data does not necessarily sum to zero. Therefore, a high R2 can result even if there is an apparent mismatch between the output of the simulation model and the data.

Which other measures would be more appropriate for comparing a simulation model to data if R2 is not suitable?

Comment: What's wrong with the mean squared error (MSE) for this purpose? i.e. $MSE = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2}{n}$), where $x_i$ = simulation model value at instance $i$ and $y_i$ is the corresponding real world price at instance $i$.

Comment: Thank you! I could use MSE. However, similar to R2, a model could have a low MSE and still be a bad model if the residuals do not sum to zero.